# How to select multiple messages in WhatsApp

Tags: whatsapp

There is no option to select multiple messages. I don't want to delete all messages. How can I select multiple messages in WhatsApp in Lumia 535

Answer (score 0):

As of now, there is no option to select multiple WhatsApp messages. You have to select and delete one by one. Yes I know, this is the most irritating part. :(

Edit:

In the latest versions, we have options to select multiple messages to delete. Tap left side on the WhatsApp messages window and you will see check boxes. Just select the messages and delete.